# How is this Swiss university job application not age discrimination?

Tags: discrimination, age, switzerland

I see a [reference to age discrimination under Swiss law](http://www.agediscrimination.info/international/Pages/Switzerland.aspx) which says:

> The prohibition of age discrimination is a fundamental right guaranteed by the 
>   Swiss Federal Constitution (Article 8, paragraph 2: No person must be
>   discriminated against due to their age).  As a fundamental right, it
>   binds the state and the authorities towards individuals.  It thus
>   applies to employment relationships governed by Swiss public law (e.g.
>   members of the civil service).

I also see on [their website](http://www.usi.ch/en/universita/about_usi/university_about_usi.htm) that the university in question (below) is a public university in Switzerland (so I would assume Swiss public law would apply):

> USI, sometimes referred to as the University of Lugano, is one of the
>   12 certified public universities in Switzerland coordinated by
>   swissuniversities.

So, how could it be that [this job add](https://eth-gethired.ch/jobs/tenure_track_assistant_professor_1/34521) is not a violation when it starts with the following text:

> **The Faculty of Informatics of the Università della Svizzera italiana
>   (USI)**, located in beautiful Lugano, Switzerland, invites **young
>   researchers** to apply for an **Assistant Professor** position.

Comment: It's pretty common in academic contexts to use the word "young" as a synonym for "junior", referring not to chronological age but to career experience.  Your academic life doesn't start at birth but at the granting of your PhD.

Answer (score 4):

In academe, "young" refers to years in career, not years since birth.